# Using arr.push vs arr.push.apply(arr, element)

Tags: javascript

I mostly use it like this:

```
arr.push(element)
```

But I have seen people using like this:

```
arr.push.apply(arr, element)
```

What's the different between this two methods?

Comment: it lets you add `[2,3]` to `[0,1]` to get `[0,1,2,3]` instead of `[0,1,[2,3]]`. you can also use its arity to push in multiple values, so the pattern is often used with `arguments` instead of a real array.

Comment: you can use .concat instead of apply, especially for multiple items, of course it will return new array

Answer (score 3):

I think it is more common when working with "lists". When using apply, you can break an array into individual arguments.

For example:

```
arr.push(0,1,2,3)
```

would be like doing this, but the initial values being in an array:

```
arr.push.apply(this, [0,1,2,3])
```

Here's a running example:

```js
var original = [1,2,3];
var arr = [];

arr.push(0);
arr.push.apply(arr, original); // pushes all the elements onto the array

console.log(arr); // 0,1,2,3
```

However, in ES6, you don't even need to use the `apply`.

```js
let original = [1,2,3];
let arr = [];

arr.push(0, ...original);

console.log(arr); // 0,1,2,3
```